# Does roll starting a car leave a skid mark?

Tags: starting, tires

Plain and simply, does roll-starting a car leave a skid mark on the road?

My mind simply can't think thru the mechanics of it. Looking around the internet, this doesn't seem do be a question people ever ask. But hah!, it sure is one my landlord is asking. (I have a finicky starter motor and a sloped driveway ;-)

Comment: As long as you don't drop the clutch too quickly, you shouldn't lock the wheels up and don't use 1st gear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can.  It depends on a number of factors but I have seen this happen myself.

Comment: Trying in first gear should skid; third gear should not.

Answer (score -2):

"Push starting" a motor vehicle, using gravity or human assist should not create surface skid marks, any more than downshifting for braking while underway. One usually selects second gear as a compromise between mechanical advantage and driveshaft/crankshaft speed, which also reduces the likelihood of creating a skid mark.

If there is a mechanical problem with the vehicle that prevents the wheels from turning properly, rubber may remain on the surface, but more likely there will be insufficient force to permit such a situation.

Once the vehicle has been started, excessive application of throttle (unnecessarily, in my opinion) can create skid marks, but that's unrelated to the actions involved in a push start.

I had an engine failure which seized the engine completely, causing the rear wheels to hop until I disengaged (engaged?) the clutch. Even then, the marks were insignificant in length, due to the hopping, but had I not disengaged the clutch, there would have been more rubber, as I was traveling about 100 kmh / 60 mph at the time. At starting speeds, there is not enough energy.